# jquery click function block

Tags: jquery, function, click

hello i have some question , how to block click function if a #health is clicked

when click function is runned i can click again but how block 2 click.

```
$('#health').click(function() {
  var count = <?=$wait_time?>;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p#health").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
      $.ajax({
       url: 'pages/map/hospital.php?heal=1',
       success: function(data) {
        $("p#health").hide();
       }
      });
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12443696/1250044

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead of `.click()`:

```
$('#health').one('click', function() {
    //etc
});
```

To clear the interval, simply use the [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) method:

```
clearInterval(countdown);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var state = true;
$(document).click(function() {
    if (state === true) {
        var count = < ? = $wait_time ? > ;
        countdown = setInterval(function() {
            $("p#health").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
            if (count == 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'pages/map/hospital.php?heal=1',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("p#health").hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            count--;
        }, 1000);

        state = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to block subsequent clicks from doing anything, try this:

```
$('#health').click(function() {
  if(countdown)
    return false;

  var count = <?=$wait_time?>;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p#health").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
      $.ajax({
       url: 'pages/map/hospital.php?heal=1',
       success: function(data) {
        $("p#health").hide();
       }
      });
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
});
```